# Contour integration of $1/x$ in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

How can one show this integral to be $0$ with contour integration in the complex plane?

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x}dx=0$$

I tried solving it using the residue theorem, but it doesn't give me $0$ but $\pi j$. Am I missing something?

Comment: This integral is divergent and not equal to $0$.

Comment: It is because your claim is false

Comment: But the result is $0$. Could this be shown with Cauchy principal value?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value#Examples

Comment: Yes. Does it work this way?

Comment: $lim_{a \to \infty} lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{-a}^{-\epsilon}\dfrac{1}{x}dx + \int_{\epsilon}^{a}\dfrac{1}{x}dx$

Answer (score 0):

You might want to say $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\ dx = \lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \int_{-n}^n f(x)\ dx$

$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \int_{-n}^{n} \frac 1x\ dx = 0$

However if the improper integral converges, it must converge even when the limits are going off to infinity at different speeds.

e.g. $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \int_{-n}^{2n} \frac 1x\ dx = \ln 2n - \ln n = \ln 2$

Getting contradictory results, we conclude that the integral does not converge.